# How to use source in docker?

Tags: django, shell, docker, virtualenv

I'm trying to use virtualenv in docker for deployment compatibility. But it went wrong when executed to this line:

```
CMD source openparty/bin/activate
```

I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, `CMD` executes a separate shell so `source` wouldn't do what you need it to even if it did work.  The `source` command reads and executes commands from the specified file.  In the case of `virtualenv` it defines a bunch of environment variables, most notably, `PATH`.  I believe that you can simply add the path of the virtual environment to the front of `PATH` and get a similar effect.

Comment: `ENV PATH $PATH:openparty/bin/activate` You mean this? It works, thank you!

Comment: I would have expected `ENV PATH openparty/bin:$PATH` since the `PATH` variable is a list of directories and `activate` is a shell script.

Comment: Is there any difference with `ENV PATH $PATH:openparty/bin/` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `activate` script is just for getting an interactive shell configured for that virtualenv. You can accomplish that with a Dockerfile like…

```
CMD ["bash", "--rcfile", "openparty/bin/activate"]
```

But if you just want to run a Python command in the context of your virtualenv, it would be neater just to refer to the virtualenv's python directly:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["openparty/bin/python", "openparty/bin/manage.py"]
```

Then you can invoke commands like

```
docker run --rm -P openparty_image runserver
```

instead of having to wrestle with a shell intermediary.